# What is the meaning of the Announcer, Booster, Publicist badges?

Tags: support, badges

The badge description reads:

> Shared a link to a question that was visited by [*number*] unique IP addresses.

What does this actually mean? How can one get these badges? If I send an email (or tweet etc.) to a friend with a link to a question, presumably the SE system wouldn't know about it. So does "share" here mean only within SE, e.g. if I post a link to a Puzzling question in the SciFi chatroom? Also does "visited" mean that all those people at different IP addresses have to reach the question *via that link* - and again how could the SE system know how they came to a given page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These badges require you to use the "share" link found on every post:

[image: screenshot]

Notice that the question ID (2852) is in its normal place in the URL, but there's another number there. That's my user ID (39). This is how Stack Exchange tracks how many people have clicked on your link.

Note that links from *within* Stack Exchange (ex. from chat, a question or answer you posted, etc.) do **not** count towards this badge. Only clicks from external sources (email, Twitter, etc.) will count.

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I wanted to know. (BTW I'd be interested to know what the button to the left of "share" does on that screenshot you gave! What can mods do to a *question* that nobody else can?)